# Dartdoc raises an error whenever I use it

Tags: dart, dartdoc

When I'm trying to document my `dart` code, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument (uri): Unknown package: Instance of '_SimpleUri'
#0      ResourceLoader.resolveResourceUri.<anonymous closure> (package:dartdoc/src/generator/resource_loader.dart:41:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      ResourceLoader.getResourceFile (package:dartdoc/src/generator/resource_loader.dart:31:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _DefaultTemplatesLoader.loadTemplate (package:dartdoc/src/generator/templates.dart:168:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Templates._create (package:dartdoc/src/generator/templates.dart:265:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      initHtmlGenerator (package:dartdoc/src/generator/html_generator.dart:22:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      Dartdoc.fromContext (package:dartdoc/dartdoc.dart:149:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/third_party/dart/third_party/pkg/dartdoc/bin/dartdoc.dart:24:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

When I use the command `dart --version`, I get this:

```
Dart SDK version: 2.13.1 (stable) (Fri May 21 12:45:36 2021 +0200) on "linux_x64"
```

`dartdoc --version`:

```
dartdoc version: 0.42.0
```

Why is this happening? I'm new to dart, so I have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: Were you able to solve? it happens to me too with Dart SDK 2.13.3, dartdoc 0.42.0.